# how to identify caller for eventbus on activity class

Tags: android, event-bus, greenrobot-eventbus, greenrobot-eventbus-3.0

i am using [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) on activity and override one event ABC.
now i am calling that event from multiple classes (`EventBus.getDefault().post(new ABC())` etc.) and i am getting callback on my activity class. so my question is : is there any way to identify caller who called that event on my activity class.

Answer (score 0):

Put something in `ABC` that tells you where the event originated from, such as via a constructor parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding a constructor which receives a tag

```
public ABC(int tag) {}
```

And then in your Activity you can proceed like this:

```
@Subscribe()
public void onEvent(ABC event) {
    switch(event.getTag()) {
        case MyService.TAG: 
            //process data from your service
            break;
        case MyFragment.TAG: 
            //process data from your fragment
            break;
    }
}
```